# Passing JavaScript ID Value to PHP for download

Tags: javascript, php

I am pretty new to PHP but I am learning fast.. I have been trying to use AJAX to Pass An ID to PHP.
With this ID I use SQL to get the path of a file from the database than use it to download the file.
However after some research this is not possible and I couldn't understand alternives... maybe there is a workaround?

These are my JavaScript function; I used JSON because I was passing an Array of IDs because I intend to use it in future for multiple downloads. I get the IDs from a table row click.

```
$('.btnDownload').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'scripts/downloadFile.php',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {id: JSON.stringify(fileID)}
                });
            });
```

And my PHP to attempt to download the file;

```
<?php
    $data = $_POST['id'];
    $data = json_decode("$data", true);
    $countArray = count($data);
    $counter = 0;
while($countArray > $counter){
        $getID = $data[$counter];
// My sql connections and queries, jumped to the fetch part
$filePath = $fetch['filePath'];
                    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filePath));

                    readfile($filePath);
                    exit;
$counter++; 
    }
?>
```

How ever this script alone works when I give a static path and run it with my browser.
I would like some help on alternatives on achieving the results.

Comment: I am very rusty with PHP, but at first glance:
1) What exactly is not working as expected? The ajax call might or might not be executed correctly, but you are not doing anything with the result it seems, or is the code incomplete?
2) it seems you are trying to read the 'fileID' parameter in PHP, but you pass 'id' from jQuery?
3) You are trying to decode some JSON input from the string "$data", not the variable $data
4) Unrelated to your question, but you should probably think about security, when you basically here has a webpage that will give the user any file on your server the user wants

Comment: whats wrong exactly is that I am using ajax call for download... and i would like some alternatives to use to pass the ID parameter and download

Comment: If you want the download to pop up as a regular link, I guess a solkution could just be to set window.location.href to 'scripts/downloadFile.php?id=' + JSON.stringify(fileID). Is this what you mean?

Comment: download doesnt pop up because of ajax, yes similar to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem relating to the popup not popping up, try something like this instead of ajax:

```
$('.btnDownload').click(function(event) {
    var url = 'scripts/downloadFile.php?id=' + JSON.stringify(fileID);
    window.location.href = url;
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

The user should be presented with a "save file" dialog and the browser will remain on the same url due to the disposition headers set by the php file.

Comment: how do i get the fileID variable on the PHP side if i use this method?

Comment: You would do that using $_GET['id']. I did not notice that you changed your code to use POST now. This example works using GET only, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter that you're passing to `downloadFile.php` is called `id`, not `ID` (for example: `data: {id: JSON.stringify(fileID)}`)

You need to update your PHP assignment to use the correct key as follows:

```
$data = $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: oh damn sorry i was messing with the code earlier because i tried some xmlhttprequest... forgot to change it

Answer (score 0):

[Mega.co.nz](https://mega.co.nz/) uses a similar approach. It requests the downloads per AJAX in order to allow a custom download progress bar. Once the download is finished, it is *copied* (technically it is downloaded from cache onto disk). You could do it somewhat like the following code. Of course, if you want to implement a custom progress bar, you'd need to fetch the unfinished response and update respectively.

```
$('.btnDownload').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : 'scripts/downloadFile.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {id : JSON.stringify(fileID)}
    })
    .done(function( response ){
        location.href = 'data:,' + btoa(response);
    });
});
```

`btoa` converts the input into a Base64 encoded string which you can then use in conjunction with the [Data URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to issue a download.